# How to chart strings using tablesorter's chart widget

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization, tablesorter

Using Mottie's tablesorter jquery plugin, I'd like to chart *strings* in addition to numbers. There's a great [example](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-chart.html) of how to create charts using *only numbers* in the tablesorter documentation. The documentation states that it is possible to chart strings using the chart_layout function by "setting the zero-based column index of the desired column to 's'", but I am unclear as to how that syntax specifically works. Any suggestions/clarifications?

Specifically, I am using the [example](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-chart.html) found on the tablesorter website, and have simply changed the last column to be text only. An example row is below:

```
<tr><td>2000</td><td>$ 1,420</td><td>$ 470</td><td>red</td></tr>
```

I've then tried setting the chart_layout widget option to {3:'s'} as the documentation appear to suggest, but this unfortunately does not work.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please try the update I just made to the chart widget in the master branch ([ref](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/commit/d50f56196994ead118ff66f8626309de4c006b5d)). The `chart_layout` should now use the correct index, but I couldn't get a good example working that would work with strings - [see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/w6yw39s9/4/) - hide all but the color column & choose vertical bar chart.

Comment: Honestly if it's just for currency I'd use css to add the $ then you don't need to use strings at all.  Just add class="currency" and in css use .currency:before { content: "$ " }. I'm in the process of modifying my codeine for charts to use strings, hopefully I'll have an example shortly.

Comment: I just saw that @Mottie made a demo already if you go through the chart types you'll see that not all chart types can plot string type inputs.  Specifically it look like only vertical bar type graphs can plot string type inputs.

Comment: @Mottie and TheSin, thanks for the prompt response! I ended up simply making a few changes to my copy of widget-chart.js to modify how it handles strings, and everything is working well now. Thanks for building such great tools.

Comment: Would you share the changes you made? Open a pull request or just pop on to freenode.net #tablesorter to chat.